# Maximum recursion depth exceeded while using Property for getters & setters

Tags: python, python-3.x, getter-setter

I'm using `property()` for setting up `getters` and `setters` for a Class
Here's the code:

```py
class Person:

    def __init__(self, email=None):
        self.email = email

    def set_email(self, value):
        self._email = value

    def get_email(self):
        return self._email

    email = property(get_email, set_email)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    try:
        contact = Person(email="abc@123")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

This code work perfect, but, when I change `self._email` to `self.email` inside `set_email()` to this:

```py
def set_email(self, value):
        self.email = value
```

I am getting:

> self.email = value
>   [Previous line repeated 494 more times]
>   **RecursionError**: maximum recursion depth exceeded

I understand that a single **underscore** before a variable denotes that the variable is for internal use only.
But I can't understand why do I need to use `self._email` even though I have used `self.email` in the constructor.

Can anyone explain why is this happening?

Comment: `self._email` and `self.email` are considered as different variables. *I understand that a single underscore before a variable denotes that the variable is for internal use only.* this is a wrong understanding.

Comment: @shaikmoeed using a single leading underscore DOES denotes an implementation variable / attribute / property / method.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers No, It's by convention developer use([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301346/what-is-the-meaning-of-a-single-and-a-double-underscore-before-an-object-name)). Can you please share any link which supports your statement?

Comment: @shaikmoeed I didn't said there was any kind of privacy enforcement - Python has zero "privacy" - I said this naming "denoted" a name used for implementation and that _should not_ (not "could not") be used by client code. The fact that it's a convention instead of a strict enforcement does'nt change this semantic. Just like ALL_UPPER names denote (pseudo) constants - Python has no notion of symbolic constants either, yet an ALL_UPPER name means you _should_ not rebind this name nor mutate what it's bound to.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Thanks for explaining. My understanding from this is.., it means, here due to *property(get_email, set_email)*,  `set_email` function is invoked when `self.email` was assigned value in the constructor and again assignment in the same function does leads it to recursion? Am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assignment `self.email = ...` will [first check](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#invoking-descriptors) whether `email` is a [data-descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#descriptor-protocol) and if so, it will invoke the corresponding setter function, in your case this is `set_email`. So when you do `self.email = ...` then effectively `set_email(self, ...)` is invoked. Within `__init__` this is not a problem, but within `set_email` this obviously leads to an infinite recursion.